# Working with MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

```
MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused
```

Trying to get all the `Mvvmcross plug-in` work in my demo project.

The sample project come from here

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus

Once I have add it from nuget

```
MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0305

> Using the generic type 'MvxPluginBootstrapAction' requires 1 type arguments
>
> XPlatformMenus.Droid

There isn't much docs for the all those plugin .

Hopefully I can get it up and running and see what it really can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be `MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction` instead of `MvxPluginBootstrapAction`

```
public class LocationPluginBootstrap
    : MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Location.PluginLoader, MvvmCross.Plugins.Location.Fused.Droid.Plugin>
{
}
```

This has been fixed, but is not released, yet: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/commit/1ff418ca2af0ede8113b6478000522b7631d1030

Comment: Nice to know there is a fix. Thanks